# I can't iterate and output the buttons

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I get such a button object in the component and I want to iterate over it and output all the buttons

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, isActive: true}
 0: {key: ':R2m:', text: 'Trading', isActive: true}
 1: {key: ':R2mH1:', text: 'Banking', isActive: false}
 isActive: true
 [[Prototype]]: Object

  <div className="flex">
    {button.isActive ? (
      <button key={button.key}>
        <div>
          <div>{button.text}</div>
        </div>
      </button>
    ) : (
      <button key={button.key}>
        <div>
          <div>{button.text}</div>
        </div>
      </button>
    )}
  </div>
```

But I don't understand why I can't do it and how do I do it

Comment: Gotta look at the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to iterate some buttons but you don't know how to do them. You could try doing something like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    {button.map((el) => <button key={el.key}>{el.text}</button>)}
  </div>
)
```